# How to get Last record from Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a one table `question_table` and one `ImageButton` (*Back*). I need to get the last inserted record from the database after clicking on the *Back*.

My row contains the following columns: `question`, `optionA`, `optionB`, `optionC`, `optionD`, and I need the data for use on my `Activity`. I create one method in database but it's not working.

Here is code for reference:

*MySQLiteHelper.java* extract:

```
public List<ObjectiveWiseQuestion> getLastInsertQuestion()
{
    // long index = 0;
    List<ObjectiveWiseQuestion>LocwiseProfileList=new ArrayList<ObjectiveWiseQuestion>();
    db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            "sqlite_sequence",
            new String[]{"seq"},
            "name = ?",
            new String[]{TABLE_QUESTION},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null );

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            ObjectiveWiseQuestion owq= new ObjectiveWiseQuestion();

            owq.setQuestion(cursor.getString(2));
            owq.setOptionA(cursor.getString(3));
            owq.setOptionB(cursor.getString(4));
            owq.setOptionC(cursor.getString(5));
            owq.setOptionD(cursor.getString(6));
            owq.setCorrectOption(cursor.getString(7));
            LocwiseProfileList.add(owq);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());

        db.close();
    }

    return LocwiseProfileList;
}
```

`OnClickListner` from *AddQuestionActivity.java*

```
imgBack.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
{                       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        msg();
        emptyFormField();

        try {
            final List<ObjectiveWiseQuestion> LocWiseProfile =  db.getLastInsertQuestion();       

            for (final ObjectiveWiseQuestion cn : LocWiseProfile)
            {   
                db=new MySQLiteHelper(getBaseContext());
                db.getWritableDatabase();
                txtQuestion.setText(cn.getQuestion());
                txtOptionA.setText(cn.getOptionA());
                txtOptionB.setText(cn.getOptionB());
                txtOptionC.setText(cn.getOptionC());
                txtOptionD.setText(cn.getOptionD());
                txtCorrectOption.setText(cn.getCorrectOption());
                db.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
});
```

Please give me some hint.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT * 
    FROM    TABLE
    WHERE   ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM TABLE);
```

**OR**

you can also used following solution:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This is very bad request for that purpose because `sqlite` should sort all records by their id (slow) before returning the result, Stephen Nguyen gave optimal request with `DESC` and `LIMIT 1`

Comment: @Hasmukh hi   govind here.. want to do satelitemenu at the right of bottom corner...
did you done it.. ?

Comment: @Govind here is the reference link, it may help you, https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu/issues/3

Comment: @Hasmukh, if suppose that column id is not just 'AUTOINCREMENT' but something else unique... is still working this solution?

Comment: @Choletski: It will only give you the last record if the column that you're ORDERing BY (or taking the MAX of) is guaranteed to increase with each new record. So you could use a timestamp column, as long as it's always increasing.

Comment: This and other answers seem to have an unstated assumption that the column they're sorting on is always increasing. That's true of autoincrement columns, but not every table has a column like that.

Comment: This is rather hacky and may lead to trouble. Process the callback and get the id using 'data.insertId' where data is whatever you name your callback return.

Comment: @ArtemZinnatullin Executing 'EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN <query>' the first query using MAX(ID) results in two searches, whereas the second query using ORDER BY results in a full table scan. So the query using MAX(ID) is the more optimal one.

Answer (score 258):

I think the top answer is a bit verbose, just use this

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The "top answer" doesn't always remain the top answer. Do you mean Hasmukh's?

Comment: sometimes it is giving the second-last value for some unknown reason...most of the time it is working fine

Comment: If the column is marked AUTOINCREMENT then SELECT MAX(ID) is better. Using  the CLI execute 'EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN <query>' your query results in a full table scan, whereas SELECT MAX(ID) results in a much faster search.

Comment: If you need to grab more than one row (below uses 500 rows), and would like to re-order them try:

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 500) ORDER BY column ASC;""") 

ASC sorts the data from descending order to ascending order after.

Answer (score 26):

Here's a simple example that simply returns the last line without need to sort anything from any column:

```
"SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1;"
```

Comment: Very nice. Makes no assumptions about the row being referenced and is probably faster sorting too.

Answer (score 25):

To get last record from your table..

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "sqlite_sequence";
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
  cursor.moveToLast();
```

Comment: You should add the WHERE = TABLE_NAME statement when your SQLite db has more than one table

Comment: @aphoe He doesn't need WHERE = TABLE_NAME because "sqlite_sequence" is the table reference.

Comment: I know of no guarantee that the last record in an unsorted query will be the last record of the table. I bet this works "often". You cannot rely on it though.

Answer (score 12):

I think it would be better if you use the method query from SQLiteDatabase class instead of the whole SQL string, which would be:

```
 Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE, allColluns, null, null, null, null, ID +" DESC", "1");
```

The last two parameters are ORDER BY and LIMIT.

You can see more at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 10):

If you have already got the cursor, then this is how you may get the last record from cursor:

```
cursor.moveToPosition(cursor.getCount() - 1);
//then use cursor to read values
```

Comment: is theres a way to get this through the creation of cursor on getContentResolver().query ?

Comment: You can simply use cursor.moveToLast();

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use SQLites [`LAST_VALUE()`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-last_value/) function in the following way.

Given this table:

| object | status | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ON | 100 |
| 1 | OFF | 102 |
| 1 | ON | 103 |
| 2 | ON | 101 |
| 2 | OFF | 102 |
| 2 | ON | 103 |
| 3 | OFF | 102 |
| 3 | ON | 103 |

You can get the last status of every object with the following query

```sql
SELECT                           
    DISTINCT OBJECT,             -- Only unique rows
    LAST_VALUE(STATUS) OVER (    -- The last value of the status column
        PARTITION BY OBJECT      -- Taking into account rows with the same value in the object column
        ORDER by time asc        -- "Last" when sorting the rows of every object by the time column in ascending order
        RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING    -- Take all rows in the patition
    ) as lastStatus
FROM
    TABLE
```

The result would look like:

| object | lastStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ON |
| 2 | ON |
| 3 | ON |

You can select additional columns to show the last value of by simply adding it with a separate windowing function:

```sql
SELECT                           
    DISTINCT OBJECT,             -- Only unique rows
    LAST_VALUE(STATUS) OVER (    -- The last value of the status column
        PARTITION BY OBJECT      -- Taking into account rows with the same value in the object column
        ORDER by time asc        -- "Last" when sorting the rows of every object by the time column in ascending order
        RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING    -- Take all rows in the patition
    ) as lastStatus,
    LAST_VALUE(TIME) OVER (
        PARTITION BY OBJECT
        ORDER by time asc
        RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) as lastTime
FROM 
    TABLE
```

| object | lastStatus | lastTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ON | 103 |
| 2 | ON | 103 |
| 3 | ON | 103 |

Or by doing some kind of concatenation:

```sql
SELECT                           
    DISTINCT OBJECT,             -- Only unique rows
    LAST_VALUE(STATUS || ':' || TIME) OVER (    -- The last value of the status column
        PARTITION BY OBJECT      -- Taking into account rows with the same value in the object column
        ORDER by time asc        -- "Last" when sorting the rows of every object by the time column in ascending order
        RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING    -- Take all rows in the patition
    ) as lastStatusTime
FROM 
    TABLE
```

| object | lastStatusTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ON:103 |
| 2 | ON:103 |
| 3 | ON:103 |

Comment: What if I wanted to include the TIME column in the result while still getting only one row per OBJECT?

Comment: Thank you, @SaaruLindestøkke. I ended up "duplicating" the windowing function for each of the other columns I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you are looking for last row of table dbstr.TABNAME, into an INTEGER column named "_ID" (for example BaseColumns._ID), but could be anyother column you want.

```
public int getLastId() {
    int _id = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(dbstr.TABNAME, new String[] {BaseColumns._ID}, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
        _id = cursor.getInt(0);
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return _id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just simple, you can move with `Cursor` **moveToLast();** method provides to move to the last record

```
cursor.moveToLast();
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to maintain my table while pulling in one row that gives me the last value in a particular column in the table. I essentially was looking to replace the `LAST()` function in excel and this worked.

```
, (Select column_name FROM report WHERE rowid = (select last_insert_rowid() from report))
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if your table has no ID column, or sorting by id doesn't return you the last row, you can always use sqlite schema native 'rowid' field.

```
SELECT column 
FROM table 
WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM table);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is no `ID` column and `ROWID` does not help.

You may use simple query, which is universal (IMHO):

```
Select * from TABLE_NAME limit 1 offset ((select count() from TABLE_NAME) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

in sqlite, there is a table called sqlite_sequence, this table contains the table name and it's last id number (if the id is auto incremented).

So, to get the last row in a table just put :

```
Select * from TABLENAME where id=(SELECT * from sqlite_sequence where name ='TABLENAME')
```

Answer (score 0):

The **previous answers** **assume** that there is an *incrementing **integer*** ID column, so `MAX(ID)` gives the last row. But sometimes the keys are of **text type**, not ordered in a predictable way. So in order to take the last 1 or N rows (#Nrows#) we can follow a **different approach**:

```
Select * From [#TableName#]  LIMIT #Nrows# offset cast((SELECT count(*)  FROM [#TableName#]) AS INT)- #Nrows#
```