# Fetching last row from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to fetch the last row from my SQLite database. Until now i have tried max,sql_sequence but nothing seems to work. I have to fetch the row values and assign it to a class variable.
Any help is appreciated as I am new to SQLite and Android.
Thanks..

Comment: do you have an autoincrement id? what column are you using the MAX operator over?

Comment: yes i have my KEY_ROW_ID="_id" which is autoincremented. I used
SELECT * FROM food_table WHERE _id = (SELECT MAX(_id)  FROM food_table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Last record from Sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902394/how-to-get-last-record-from-sqlite)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have already got the `cursor`, then this is how you may get the last record from `cursor`:

```
cursor.moveToPosition(cursor.getCount() - 1);
```

then use `cursor` to read values

or

do it like this

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
cursor.moveToLast();
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE);
```

Comment: i have added one more code.. and please check is your cursor null bcoz u din't created object

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!!aaaaahhhh!! I so love u.. Thanks a ton for the help!! was working on this since past 2 days..

Comment: hahha... Appreacite so much saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM food_table
ORDER BY _id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am still not getting it. I get android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested with a size of 1

Comment: Can you execute this same statement from command line? In adb shell, try to execute `sqlite3 yoursqlitedatabase.db`, and then type and execute statement above. Maybe your database does not exist?

Comment: Thanks a ton for investing your precious time in helping me out. The solution by user123 helped.. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try This It May Help You It Gives Last Record Of Your Table**

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from  TableName", null);
mCursor.moveToLast();
```

**Now Get The Data From The Cursor**

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a table called `sqlite_sequence` which stores the highest primary key of all the tables in the SQLite db. So use the following

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM  sqlite_sequence WHERE name = table_name";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
cursor.moveToLast();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modified query to in last row....but you have to sort in a order using any column like in my case I have a **serial_no** column in my **Employee** table so my query is

> `SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY serial_no DESC LIMIT 1`

- limit 1 is in your case because you want only last record only