# Android: SQLite GROUP BY

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

In my application, I have a database table containing chat messages,like below.

```
|---------------------------------------------|
|message      | from  | to   |time
|-------------|-------|------|----------------|
|Hello        |user1  |user2 |2015-2-26 1:15PM|
|-------------|-------|------|----------------|
|Watsup       |user2  |user1 |2015-2-26 1:25PM|
|-------------|-------|------|----------------|
|Hows u?      |user3  |user1 |2015-2-26 2:15PM|
|-------------|-------|------|----------------|
|Im fine      |user1  |user3 |2015-2-26 2:35PM|
----------------------------------------------|
```

In my messages page I want list messages from all users. In this condition assume, "user1" as log-inned user,

Currently I am using query,

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY from
```

and I am getting output as,

```
    |--------------------------------|
    |user2                           |
    |Hello                           |
    |--------------------------------|
    |user2                           |
    |Watsup                          |
    |--------------------------------|
    |user3                           |
    |Hows u?                         |
    |--------------------------------|
    |user3                           |
    |Im fine                         |
    |--------------------------------|
```

What I want is distinct rows (like all chat apps),

```
|--------------------------------|
|user2                           |
|Watsup                          |
|--------------------------------|
|user3                           |
|Im fine                         |
|--------------------------------|
```

So, how can I write a sqlite query to fetch rows like this?

Comment: I am baffled at how you suggested those two messages from the output.  Can you elaborate on the logic you want to implement?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I want to get the latest message.And there is a column for date and time in my table. Sorry I missed it :)

Comment: Can you post your table structure? With column time and date

Comment: Have you tried an order by as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902394/how-to-get-last-record-from-sqlite?

Answer (score 2):

You can try as below with the `Group By` and `Having` clause.

```
     SELECT message,from
     FROM 
        table 
    GROUP BY from
    HAVING Max(time) = Time
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but getting same result as before.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY MIN(from, to), MAX(from, to) ORDER BY time DESC
```

This will not treat GROUP BY of (userA, userB) and (userB, userA) as different and combine the two, so you will get the output as you want.

You can also JOIN this with your Contacts table so that you can get all the data you need to show on the "Recent Chats" screen in one go. Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages m, Contacts c WHERE (m.from = c.userid OR m.to = c.userid) GROUP BY MIN(m.from, m.to), MAX(m.from, m.to) ORDER BY m.time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT AND ORDERBY :

```
SELECT DISTINCT from,message FROM table ORDER BY time DESC;
```