# Get last inserted column value of selected query in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

My query is giving me the sum of `col_balance` but I want the last inserted COL_BALANCE value by a particular (missing word). It must be something like:

```
select COL_BALANCE  from TABLE_NAME2  where name =(select col_bal from query where count is count -1 )

String selectQuery = " SELECT "+"sum(" + COL_BALANCE + ")"+ " FROM " + TABLE_NAME2  +  " WHERE " + COL_CUST_NAME + "= '" + name + "';";
```

Comment: How do you identify the row that is the last? Do you have a timestamp or a an increasing ID?

Comment: The solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902394/how-to-get-last-record-from-sqlite  tells how to get the last record from a table. Is this what you need?

Answer (score -1):

**SQLite**

This is available using the [SQLite last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) function:

"The last_insert_rowid() function returns the ROWID of the last row insert from the database connection which invoked the function. The last_insert_rowid() SQL function is a wrapper around the sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() C/C++ interface function."