# How do I get the newest time value in Android Java SQL in my database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an SQL database with two columns "Message" and "Datetime". I want to know when the last entry was added. I want to get the highest datetime value.

What the most efficient way to query the database in Android/Java to get this value?

Comment: Please see if this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902394/how-to-get-last-record-from-sqlite

Comment: Are you using SQLite? What is the type of the column for "Datetime"? Some code would be useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have SQLite:

If your column is TEXT or REAL then this will give you newest item:

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY date(column) DESC Limit 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY datetime(column) DESC Limit 1
```

or simply

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY column DESC Limit 1
```

Comment: You don't need to call `date()` or `datetime()` for this.