# Inner Join two tables and return greatest value from second table for each entry in first table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How would I construct a query in SQLite that selects every row from a `TABLE1`, and also selects one row from a `TABLE2` where:

- There is a match between an `id` value from `TABLE1`, and;
- If there is more than one `id` match in `TABLE2`, only the highest value in another `DATE` column is returned.

Here is the table arrangement I have right now. The value in the `r_identifier` column corresponds to the `t_id` value in `TABLE1`:

**TABLE1 ("Tanks")**

```
+------+--------------+-------+
| t_id |    t_name    | t_vol |
+------+--------------+-------+
|    1 | A Tank       |    23 |
|    2 | Another Tank |    48 |
+------+--------------+-------+
```

**TABLE2("Readings")**

```
+------+--------------+--------+---------+
| r_id | r_identifier | r_date | r_value |
+------+--------------+--------+---------+
|    0 |            1 |   5000 |       5 |
|    1 |            1 |   6000 |       7 |
|    2 |            2 |   7000 |       4 |
|    3 |            1 |   8000 |       3 |
+------+--------------+--------+---------+
```

And here is the table I would like to return from my query. Because there are multiple entries with the `r_identifier` of `1`, only the one with the highest value in `r_date` is returned:

```
+------+--------------+-------+------+--------------+--------+---------+
| t_id |    t_name    | t_vol | r_id | r_identifier | r_date | r_value |
+------+--------------+-------+------+--------------+--------+---------+
|    1 | A Tank       |    23 |    3 |            1 |   8000 |       5 |
|    2 | Another Tank |    48 |    2 |            2 |   7000 |       4 |
+------+--------------+-------+------+--------------+--------+---------+
```

The closest I've been able to manage so far is with the following statement, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16043791/1219389):

```
SELECT t.*, r.* FROM t INNER JOIN r ON t._id=r_identifier ORDER BY r_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

This returns the correct values, but for only one "tank" - the first one in the table.

**Edit**
I forgot to mention in my original question that I wanted to retrieve *every* value in `TABLE1` even if there were no entries in `TABLE2` that had a matching value in the `r_identifier` column. Using [Gordon Linoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40451004/1219389) as a guide though I was able to come up with the following which is working well:

```
SELECT t.*, r.* 
FROM t LEFT OUTER JOIN 
r ON t._id=r_identifier 
WHERE 
    (r_date IS NULL) OR 
    (r_date=(SELECT MAX(r2.r_date) 
    FROM r r2 
    WHERE r.r_identifier=r2.r_identifier));
```

Comment: you can increase limit value as your requirement it will return more than one value...! as limit 2 or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use a `WHERE` clause with a correlated subquery to get the maximum date:

```
SELECT t.*, r.*
FROM t INNER JOIN
     r
     ON t._id = r.r_identifier
WHERE r.r_date = (SELECT MAX(r2.r_date)
                  FROM r r2
                  WHERE r.r_identifier = r2.r_identifier
                 );
```