# How to select the last entry of an SQLIte DB without knowing the id?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I´m currently working with SQLite databases on android.
i have a simple database with 4 columns (id, c1, c2, c3)

i have a methode that returns the last entry of a specific column. I don´t know the id of the entry, but i know its always the most recent one.

currently i´m doing it like this:

```
 public int Select(String column){
    Log.i(TAG, column +" request");
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


    Cursor cs = db.query(table, new String[]{column,null,null,null},null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cs!=null && cs.moveToFirst()){
        cs.moveToLast();
        return Integer.parseInt(cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(column)));
    }
}
```

at runtime, cs is always null and i can´t figure out why.
What am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: Looks to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9902506/3173441. Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess you can use ORDER BY in query and get id of first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the last entry in the table then you must have a column that indicates the order of the insertions of the rows, say a datetime column like `created_at` and then you could do:

```
SELECT columnname FROM tablename ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

If there isn't such a column, then you could use the column `id` but only if you have defined it as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, (even without the keyword `AUTOINCREMENT` you can't be sure of the order because ids may be reused after deletions and insertions):

```
SELECT columnname FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

So your code must be:

```
public Integer select(String columnName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT " + columnName + " FROM " + tableName + " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    Cursor cs = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    Integer result = null;
    if(cs.moveToFirst()) {
        try {
            result = cs.getInt(0); // the query returns only 1 column so it is safe to use its index
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, columnName + " Invalid integer value");
        } 
    }
    cs.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

You can use the above method like:

```
Integer value = select("yourColumnName");
```

and it will return the last entry or `null` if the table is empty or the value returned is not a valid integer.

I use `Integer` as the return type of the method `select()` because you use it too.
If the column has a different data type you must change it accordingly.

Comment: thank you.turns out that my problem was with the constructor of the database class, but i learned something from your answer  :)